# Download events from full calendar

Tags: html, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar in my website.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I have been going through the documentation of full calendar to check if it is possible to create an ics file from full calendar. I have not been able to find any solution.
Is it possible to create ics file from full calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is based on .NET you can try to use the DDay.iCal at http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/.